# two different dates are returned in momentjs timezone for same set time?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

Even the value I set for the time in the moment.js timezones same following two different approaches the value of the date returned is different

1. `moment("02:00","HH:mm").tz('America/Chicago').format()`

returns `2022-03-31T15:30:00-05:00`

2. `moment().tz('America/Chicago').set({hour:"02",minute:"00"})`

returns `2022-04-01T02:00:02-05:00`

Can anyone please help me in understanding why is it so?

```js
console.log(moment("02:00","HH:mm").tz('America/Chicago').format());
console.log(moment().tz('America/Chicago').set({hour:"02",minute:"00"}).format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can anyone please also address another part of the question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71707164/13871017

Answer (score 3):

You have different approach with two examples:

In first example you do:

1. Take *local* date (`2021-04-01 12:15`)
2. Set time for *local* date to 02:00 (`2021-04-01 02:00`)
3. Move that particular *local* date to other time zone (so e.g. from `+02:00` tz to `-05:00` - moves back by 7 hours) (`2021-03-31 15:00`)

While in second example you do:

1. Take *local* date (`2021-04-01 12:15`)
2. Move that *local* date to other time zone (`2021-04-01 06:15`)
3. Set time for *moved time* to `02:00` (`2021-04-01 02:00`)

Comment: I would change #3 to "Set time in other timezone to 02:00". Also, changing the timezone doesn't really "move" anything, it just changes the offset used when displaying the date and time. :-)

Comment: @RobG "Moves" representation of timestamp

Comment: Which one is the good approach if I want to set a time for that timezone, the second one?

Comment: @prashanthh—the second. It sets the timezone of the moment object so that everything from then on is in the context of the timezone, such as setting dates and times, adding/subtracting dates and times, formatting, etc.